# SNI - statistics

Tags: web, statistics, sni

I did a deep research online. but I coudnt find any statistics for how many sites actually use SNI

only thing I could find is which browsers support SNI

can someone say is it's common solution? or maybe no one use it?

Thanks
Joe

Answer (score 0):

Netcraft [only sells](http://www.netcraft.com/internet-data-mining/ssl-survey/) this information. There seem to be a lack of publicly available statistics on TLS extension adoption in the wild...